# TSQL While Loop over months in year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an output that I need to achieve and I am not too certain how to go about it.

I first need to start by looping over each month in the year and using that month in a select statement to check for data.

For example:

```
Select * from table where MONTH(A.[submissionDate]) = 1
Select * from table where MONTH(A.[submissionDate]) = 2
Select * from table where MONTH(A.[submissionDate]) = 3
```

My end result is to create this XML output to use with a chart plugin. It needs to include the months even if there is no data which is why I wanted to loop through each month to check for it.

```
    <root>
   <dataSet>
      <areaDesc>Area 1</areaDesc>
      <data>
         <month>January</month>
         <monthValue>1</monthValue>
         <submissions>0</submissions>
      </data>
      <data>
         <month>February</month>
         <monthValue>2</monthValue>
         <submissions>7</submissions>
      </data>
      <data>
         <month>March</month>
         <monthValue>3</monthValue>
         <submissions>5</submissions>
      </data>
   </dataSet>
   <dataSet>
      <areaDesc>Area 2</areaDesc>
      <data>
         <month>January</month>
         <monthValue>1</monthValue>
         <submissions>0</submissions>
      </data>
      <data>
         <month>February</month>
         <monthValue>2</monthValue>
         <submissions>7</submissions>
      </data>
      <data>
         <month>March</month>
         <monthValue>3</monthValue>
         <submissions>5</submissions>
      </data>
   </dataSet>
</root>
```

I may be way over thinking this but I'm hoping I talking it through may help me out a little.

Here is my current set up of how I get some other stats:

```
--Temp table     
DECLARE @areas TABLE (
    area VARCHAR (100));
IF @dept = 'global'
   OR @dept = ''
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @areas (area)
        SELECT DISTINCT(AreaDesc)
        FROM dbo.EmpTable;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @areas
        SELECT @dept;
    END

IF (@action = 'compare')
        BEGIN
            SELECT   DATENAME(month, A.[submissionDate]) AS [month],
                     MONTH(A.[submissionDate]) AS [monthValue],
                     count(A.[submissionID]) AS submissions,
                     B.[AreaDesc]
            FROM     empowermentSubmissions AS A
            INNER JOIN empTable AS B
            ON A.[nomineeQID] = B.[QID]
            WHERE    YEAR(A.[submissionDate]) = @year
                     AND A.[statusID] = 3
                     AND A.[locationID] IN (SELECT location
                                            FROM   @table)
            GROUP BY DATENAME(month, A.[submissionDate]), MONTH(A.[submissionDate]), B.[AreaDesc]
            ORDER BY [monthValue] ASC
            FOR      XML PATH ('dataSet'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
        END
    ELSE
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need a while loop? From your problem, it sounds like you just need to do a COUNT of submissions with a GROUP BY Area, YEAR(A.SubmissionDate), MONTH(A.SubmissionDate).

Comment: The problem is though that there could be data missing for a month in a specific area and if it wasn't included at all then the alignment of the data would be off. So I was trying to always have the 12 months of data even if it was 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do a FOR XML structure to get the exact result set you're looking for in one go, I think. I put this together with what I could glean about your XML. Just change the name of the table variable here to your real table name and this should work.

**EDIT:** changed up the query to match the definition from the posted query. Updated the `data` element where clause to maintain month instantiation when zero counts were found in a month.

**EDIT:** Added Status requirement.

**EDIT:** Moved areaDesc criteria for constant month output.

```
declare @empowermentSubmissions table (submissionID int primary key identity(1,1), submissionDate datetime, nomineeQID INT, statusID INT)
declare @empTable table (QID int primary key identity(1,1), AreaDesc varchar(10))
declare @n int = 1

while @n < 50
begin
    insert into @empTable (AreaDesc) values ('Area ' + cast((@n % 2)+1 as varchar(1)))
    set @n = @n + 1
end
set @n = 1
while @n < 500
begin
    insert into @empowermentSubmissions (submissionDate, nomineeQID, StatusID) values (dateadd(dd,-(cast(rand()*600 as int)),getdate()), (select top 1 QID from @empTable order by newid()), 3 + (@n % 2) - (@n % 3) )
    set @n = @n + 1
end


declare @year int = 2014

select (
    select (
        select (
            select e1.areaDesc
            from @empTable e1
            where e1.areaDesc = e2.areaDesc
            group by e1.areaDesc
            for xml path(''),type
            )
            , (
                select [month], [monthValue], count(s1.submissionID) as submissions
                from (
                    select @year [Year]
                        , datename(month,dateadd(mm,RowID-1,@year-1900)) [Month]
                        , month(dateadd(mm,RowID-1,@year-1900)) [MonthValue]
                    from (
                        select *, row_number()over(order by name) as RowID
                        from master..spt_values
                        ) d
                    where d.RowID <= 12
                    ) t
                    left join (
                        select s3.submissionID, s3.submissionDate, e3.AreaDesc
                        from @empowermentSubmissions s3
                            inner join @empTable e3 on s3.nomineeQID = e3.QID
                        where s3.statusID = 3
                            and e3.areaDesc = e2.areaDesc
                        ) s1 on year(s1.submissionDate) = t.[Year]
                        and month(s1.submissionDate) = t.[MonthValue]
                group by [Month], [MonthValue]
                order by [MonthValue]
                for xml path('data'),type
            )
        for xml path(''),type
        ) dataset
    from @empowermentSubmissions s2
        inner join @empTable e2 on s2.nomineeQID = e2.QID
    group by e2.areaDesc
    for xml path(''), type
    ) root
for xml path (''), type
```

Comment: I will give this a try first thing tomorrow when I get to work. I really appreciate the time spent on it

Comment: I am having a little trouble getting this to work with my setup - I have added my current SP code to the OP if you see this again

Comment: Changed up the structure to match your query, and desired output. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is amazing - Worked perfectly when I plugged my own tables in there. Can't thank you enough for this. I would NOT have even came close to writing something like this on my own

Comment: I added one additional where clause `from empowermentSubmissions s2
        inner join empTable e2 on s2.nomineeQID = e2.QID
 WHERE s2.statusID = 3` and because the status was 2 and not 3, the month didnt even show up at all. Any way to easily say include it even if there are none with that status?

Comment: @SBB: Thanks for the compliment. As to the status, I apparently dropped that ball. You'll want to add it to the s3 level of the data query path, as this is where the submissions are being counted from. I included this in my latest edit.

Comment: Awesome - I am trying to figure something out in the query that I may be over looking. It appears that there may be a hiccup with the data. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SJNLfD0e In that output, it is skipping months that have data when it belongs to another area. For example, feb has data in the area of support which shows up fine, but it should also show up in customer solutions as 0. Seems like it skips around

Comment: Hmm...I see that in the pastebin output, but I'm not getting that in my sample, [here](http://pastebin.com/we92N8qr). You moved the criteria to be `where s3.StatusID = 3`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59672/discussion-between-sbb-and-jaaz-cole).

Comment: could you post your current query that's giving this output?

Comment: edited the answer to reflect proper criteria. The s1.areaDesc = e2.areaDesc was misplaced, and limiting monthly output. This should be the final version.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great application for a "Dates" table or view. Create a new table in your database with schema like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Dates (
    Month INT,
    MonthName VARCHAR(20)
)
```

Populate this table with the years and months you may want to aggregate over. Then, you can make your query like:

```
SELECT 
    Area
    Dates.MonthName,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
    dbo.Dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Submissions
        AND Dates.Month = MONTH(Submissions.SubmissionDate)
GROUP BY
    Dates.MonthName,
    Area
```

The LEFT OUTER JOIN will give you one row for every Year and Month in the dates table, and a count of any submissions on that month. You end up with output like:

```
Area    | MonthName | Count
Area 1  | Jan       | 0
Area 2  | Feb       | 2
```

&c.

Comment: This may help you understand what I am trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/ The X axis will always be the same (12 months of the year) but I need to create the series data (Y Axis) which will be an array for each Area. The Y axis is going to expect data in 12 places or else the alignment is going to be off. This is why I was trying to go through all 12 months regardless of if they had data or not

Comment: Updated answer... you can simply change the dates table to have a MonthName as well as the month, and eliminate the year from the grouping if you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a tally table to get the months:

```
SELECT TOP 12 IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS N
INTO #tally
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns sc1

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,t.N-1,'2014-01-01')) AS namemonth, t.N AS monthvalue, COUNT(tbl.submissionDate) AS submissions, tbl.Area
FROM #tally t
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl ON MONTH(tbl.submissionDate) = t.N
GROUP BY t.n, tbl.Area

DROP TABLE #tally
```

Comment: Might want to change COUNT(1) into a count based on tbl.someID, as your solution will turn 0 counts into 1s.